# Best practice for managing RethinkDB connections in Express.js

Tags: rethinkdb

When should rethinkdb connections be opened and closed in the context of a expressjs application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to go:

1. Open and close one connection per express request
2. Use a connection pool - rethinkdbdash is pretty good at that in this case. It has a connection pool and automatically take care of connection (you never see a connection with rethinkdbdash).

Comment: End up opening a connection per request

Comment: This does become a challenge when using socket.io in the application too

Comment: Why? You can bind a RethinkDB connection to the socket. Or just use a pool across all your sockets.